# Top 10 players ranked by score + curent player score

Tags: mysql

For a server Game...
I have table Jewels:

```
rank,player_id, plscore.
```

I want to show the top 10 players sorted by their score, high to low, plus the current player score if the current player isn't in the top 10.
It can be my or your score if i/you are not in the top 10 currently. 
The maximum number of Jewels which can be picked up is 70.

Example(desired):

```
__________________________________
  rank  |   player_id  |   plscore

   1        zorro007        70
   2        trus            70
   3        edvino          67
   4        snow.boy        65
   5        anida           61 
   6        nadal_raffo     58
   7        syskowitz       43
   8        misterProKill   27
   9        katamadu134     22
   10       ewrgreen89      16
   .             .          .
   .             .          .
   94       CURRENT PLAYER  7
___________________________________
```

Image: http://postimg.org/image/3x8ktdjct/

Comment: SELECT rank, player_id, plscore FROM table_name WHERE rank < 11 OR player_id = current_player_id ORDER BY rank;

Comment: @Marco Frost Why not put that as an answer... comments are for comments.

Comment: @meewoK Personally I'll add something as a comment if it's very short, as I feel like I have to add more descriptions and explain why the solution that OP chose wasn't the correct one etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT rank, player_id, plscore 
FROM table_name WHERE rank < 11 
OR player_id = current_player_id 
ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: but, how to get current player  for all other players? I have used name "CURRENT PLAYER" for example, but it can be John, Oliver, Martina... Every player who watching his score JUST NOW. It is not any certain player, with certain name. It can be everyone.

Comment: You just replace `current_player_id` with the player_id of the one which is watching the score at the moment. To get that id is a task of your game. Usually you realize this by getting the player_id from the login information of the player. But to give you better advice with that, you should give us some more code.